# How do i edit a Javascript / Bootbox/ Bootstrap confirm window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I have a simple bootbox / javascript confirm window at:

https://www.guard-gate.com/test2/index.html

1. How do I make the Success button link to google, the Danger button link to yahoo.com and the Click Me button close the box?
2. How do I change the position of the window to get it in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this for setting the modal in the middle:

```
var windowHeightCalc = $(window).height() / 2,
    modalHeightCalc = $('.modal-content').height();

$('.modal').css({ 'margin-top': [windowHeightCalc - modalHeightCalc, 'px'].join('') });
```

You don't really need Bootbox for making the modal just use the default Bootstrap modal - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You can modify it and change the links as you wish. To open it simply run:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and to hide it:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Apologies as i'm not familiar with the code/language, where would i paste the above code?

Answer (score 0):

In [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) you could try using that what the documentation advise you:

```js
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    danger: {
      label: "Danger!",
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Click ME!",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In the callbacks you could do everything. For JS-redirects you can do:

```js
window.location.href = "http://whatever.com";
```

Comment: he wants to get to the middle of a page so you probably want to give an id to the div that you want to go to and use window.location.hash then the hashtag and not another page.

Comment: But "I want to link to" mean that these should be links to that page?

Comment: @copypaste it is kinda true his question is not clear. THe fault is not coming from you. He wants to get both to the middle of his page which will be using a window.location.hash in js and he wants to get to other pages which will be using window.location.href

Comment: Sorry i'm not familiar with javascript, where should i paste the window.logcation.ref code?

Comment: In the Code there are `callbacks` (callback = function). Those callbacks are called when clicking on this Button - so clicking on button where the `label:` is `success` then the callback in the code next to this title is called.